# What is the difference between video and voice call in Azure Communication Services apart from just video session?

Tags: azure, service

I am trying to implement Azure Communication Services in my application. However, I am a bit confused between voice and video call. What is the difference between both of them apart from the visual communication? We can turn off the video and would it be the same as voice call then or are there any other differences?

I have tried looking at the Azure Communication Services SDK classes. Both are using the same interfaces.
May be because of some confusion, I want to find some difference between these two apart from just visual communication.